# problem with finding duplicates (64 characters or more)

Tags: python

Win10, Python 3.9.6
Hello, I want the code to display duplicates in the text (like a random set of characters that is repeated 2 or more times), with a small number of characters it works fine, with a large number (64 or more) it refuses. How to fix? Help me find a solution

it needs to be like this

[image]

```py
def read_lines(input_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
        return file.read().splitlines()

def line_comb(st):
    res = set()
    n = len(st)

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            res.add(st[i: j+1])

    return res

lines = read_lines(input_file)
result = line_comb(lines[0])

for i in range(1, len(lines)):
    result &= line_comb(lines[i])
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it refuses"?  Does it not return an expected outcome? Does the program emit an error (if so what error do you get?) or the program halts in the middle?

Comment: Well, it is O(n**3) algorithm. I am surprised that it breaks for 64 characters though. May you explain more and also provide us a test data nad/or your exact error message/wrong behavior description?

Comment: no error. white screen (it seems that the program is running, but nothing happens). when I close the process it says "kill"